# django+south: migrate command doesn't create table in the database

Tags: database, django, migration, data-migration, django-south

I have a strnage problem.
My django project has myapp module/application. My project uses south to do the schema migrations.
On localhost i have run `./manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial`, then i have run migrate command.

But when in production environment i execute `migrate` command, this doesn't create the correponding table (of myapp models) in database.

It's strange because if i execute `migrate --list`, myapp has to migration and they are all marked (with * symbol ).

So, i'm thinking about deleting myapp and recreating it from scratch (with corresponding migrations). Is there better solution?

EDIT:
i have tried to delete myapp and to recreate it from scratch. So i have also delete tables of myapp in database (on localhost and on production server), and after all i have executed:

`schemamigration myapp --initial` command on localhost

`migrate myapp` command on localhost

`migrate myapp 0001 --fake` on production server

but South continues to not create the tables of myapp in database of production server.

Comment: Why do you call `migrate ... --fake`? `--fake` makes South only mark migration as successful but do not touch actual DB schema.

Answer (score 1):

If you accidentally or intentionally dropped a table in your DB and your are trying to run `./manage migrate myapp`This will not create the dropped table in your DB. 
Because South does not touch base with your DB.

In case you want to re-create your table. Migrate your schema to a previous version and migrate it latest. Please use the below code accordingly

```
manage.py migrate myapp 0002 --fake
manage.py migrate myapp
```

note: 002 is your previous migration version.

Answer (score 0):

if you deleted your tables you shouldn't be running `--fake` unless you did a `manage.py syncdb` first. With no table, you should be able to run `python manage.py migrate myapp` and be done with it (or a `manage.py syncdb`). The first migration created by `--initial` has create table statements in it.

`--fake` explicitly tells south to not do anything but pretend it migrated (performed DB changes) and mark the history table as such.

Comment: So: i delete all tables (on localhost and on production server) of myapp. Then i run `syncdb` or `schemamigration --initial`. Then i deploy the project. And then?
It continues to not create database tables on production server with this method.

Comment: @GiovanniChetelodicoafare, if all tables are deleted, just running `migrate` will create the tables if you have the `0001_initial` migration files in the app directories. Make sure the `south_migrationhistory` table is up to date, and has no entries for your apps that you are resetting.

Comment: I have decided to not use South for myapp because i didn't still change models of myapp. So running syncdb on production server i have resolved the problem. I will use South for myapp if i change models.py and i have to do migrations. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but  had this same problem and I found that the problem was that my manage.py was pointing to the wrong settings file hence wrong DB. Ensure your manage.py is pointing to the correct settings file and migrations are being made to the correct DB. This can arise if you are using multiple manage.py files or multiple settings files.